# Validando se existe ou não usuário com Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Criei um cadastro, web, no Firebase.
Consigo me cadastrar, mas se me logo com um email e senha válido, não sou redirecionado para dentro do sistema. E se coloco um email e senha qualquer, ele não mostrar a frase "Usuário ou senha inválido" que programei pra ser exibido

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form class="form-signin formularioLogin">

            <h3 align="center">Domanda</h3>

            <label>E-mail do Estabelecimento</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="admin.email"
                placeholder="barbarshop@barbershop.com.br">
            </div>

            <label>Senha</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control adminSenha" type="password" ng-model="admin.senha">
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-block btn-success btnLogar" ng-click="logar(admin)">Entrar</button>
            <div>{{ loginErro }}</div>

            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btnLogar" ng-click="cadastrar(admin)">Cadastrar</button>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.logar = function(admin){

    var email = admin.email;
    var password = admin.senha;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then( function ( result ) {
        //Usuário autenticado com sucesso
        //Seu código para redirecionar vem aqui.
        console.log(result);
        $location.path('/inicial');
    }, function ( error ) {
        //Ops, ocorreu um erro, pode deixar seu código tratando o erro aqui
        console.log('erro: '+error);
        $location.path('/');
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tratando apenas o cenário de erro, com o catch...

Como é uma promise você deve tratar também o que fazer se der certo no "then".

Ex:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then( function ( result ) {
    //Usuário autenticado com sucesso
    //Seu código para redirecionar vem aqui.
}, function ( error ) {
    //Ops, ocorreu um erro, pode deixar seu código tratando o erro aqui
})
```

Comment: Veja a modificação que fiz no código... Nem esse console.log('tudo certo!') não aparece quando digito email e senha válidos.

Comment: Gustavo, você está chamando a função signInWithEmailAndPassword e tratando o "catch", sempre que cair no catch, é por que ocorreu algum erro,  quando der tudo certo nunca irá cair ali, por isso postei a resposta usando o then, a função signInWithEmailAndPassword é uma promise, onde o retorno dela é um success que você trata com o "then" ou um error que vocÊ trata com o "catch", no seu caso você está só tratando o error

Comment: Substitua sua chamada pela minha acima, e coloque um console log dentro do primeiro bloco onde tem o result que é onde da tudo certo e depois adicione um console.log no error e realize alguns testes

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword verifique que o retorno da função é um promise

Comment: Aqui tem a documentação para a utilização de promises com angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Certo Bruno. Mas agora, mesmo eu colocando um login válido eu não sou redirecionado pra dentro do app.

Comment: Testei de novo... Só após um segundo clique em logar dai é que entro no sistema... Sabes como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: As promises são assíncronas, faça um teste com mais calma, clique e espere um pouco, se funcionar, aconselho adicionar um loading, para tirar essa sensação de que nada aconteceu, pode ser que demore um pouco mesmo.

Comment: Nada... Esperei meio minuto e nada kkkkk

Comment: Não cai no sucesso e nem no erro? Veja se não acontece nenhum erro no seu console, pois deveria funcionar

Comment: Não kkkkk Eu trabalho monitorando o console kkkk

Comment: Não consigo pensar em nenhum cenário, se a chamada da promise foi feita, ela deve retornar um sucesso ou um erro, nunca vi nenhum cenário onde não há retorno nenhum e apenas no segundo click funcionaria.. :/